# how to create a DataAccessLayer?

Tags: c#

i am creating a database applicatin in .Net. I am using a DataAccessLayer for communicating .net objects with database but i am not sure that this class is correct or not  Can anyone cross check it and rectify any mistakes

```
namespace IDataaccess
{
    #region Collection Class

    public class SPParamCollection : List<SPParams>
    {

    }
    public class SPParamReturnCollection : List<SPParams>
    {

    }
    #endregion
    #region struct
    public struct SPParams
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public object Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public ParameterDirection ParamDirection
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public SqlDbType Type
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Size
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string TypeName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        // public string datatype;
    }
    #endregion
    /// <summary>
    /// Interface DataAccess Layer implimentation New version 
     /// </summary>

    public interface IDataAccess
    {
        DataTable getDataUsingSP(string spName);
        DataTable getDataUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection);
        DataSet getDataSetUsingSP(string spName);
        DataSet getDataSetUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection);
        SqlDataReader getDataReaderUsingSP(string spName);
        SqlDataReader getDataReaderUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection);
        int executeSP(string spName);
        int executeSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, bool addExtraParmas);
        int executeSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection);
        DataTable getDataUsingSqlQuery(string strSqlQuery);
        int executeSqlQuery(string strSqlQuery);
        SPParamReturnCollection executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection);
        SPParamReturnCollection executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection);
        SPParamReturnCollection executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection, bool addExtraParmas);
        int executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, ref SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection);
        object getScalarUsingSP(string spName);
        object getScalarUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection);
    }
}

using IDataaccess;
namespace Dataaccess
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class DataAccess Layer implimentation New version 
    /// </summary>

    public class DataAccess : IDataaccess.IDataAccess
    {
        #region Public variables
        static string Strcon;
        DataSet dts = new DataSet();

        public DataAccess()
        {
            Strcon = sReadConnectionString();
        }
        private string sReadConnectionString()

        {
            try
            {
                //dts.ReadXml("C:\\cnn.config");
                //Strcon = dts.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

                //System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                //Strcon = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

                // Add an Application Setting.




               //Strcon = "Data Source=192.168.50.103;Initial Catalog=erpDB;User ID=ipixerp1;Password=NogoXVc3";
             Strcon =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"];
                //Strcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[0].ToString();
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return Strcon;
        }

        public SqlConnection connection;
        public SqlCommand cmd;
        public SqlDataAdapter adpt;
        public DataTable dt;
        public int intresult;
        public SqlDataReader sqdr;
        #endregion
        #region Public Methods
        public DataTable getDataUsingSP(string spName)
        {
            return getDataUsingSP(spName, null);
        }
        public DataTable getDataUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        int count, param = 0;
                        if (spParamCollection == null)
                        { param = -1; }
                        else
                        {
                            param = spParamCollection.Count;
                        }
                        for (count = 0; count < param; count++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                        }
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        dt = new DataTable();
                        adpt.Fill(dt);
                        return (dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }

        public DataSet getDataSetUsingSP(string spName)
        {
            return getDataSetUsingSP(spName, null);
        }
        public DataSet getDataSetUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        int count, param = 0;
                        if (spParamCollection == null)
                        {
                            param = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            param = spParamCollection.Count;
                        }
                        for (count = 0; count < param; count++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                        }
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        adpt.Fill(ds);
                        return ds;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        public SqlDataReader getDataReaderUsingSP(string spName)
        {
            return getDataReaderUsingSP(spName, null);
        }
        public SqlDataReader getDataReaderUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection)
        {

            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        int count, param = 0;
                        if (spParamCollection == null)
                        { param = -1; }
                        else
                        {
                            param = spParamCollection.Count;
                        }
                        for (count = 0; count < param; count++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                        }
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        sqdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        return (sqdr);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        public int executeSP(string spName)
        {
            return executeSP(spName, null);
        }
        public int executeSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, bool addExtraParmas)
        {
            try
            {

                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        int count, param = 0;
                        if (spParamCollection == null)
                        { param = -1; }
                        else
                        {
                            param = spParamCollection.Count;
                        }
                        for (count = 0; count < param; count++)
                        {
                            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                            if (addExtraParmas)
                            {
                                par.TypeName = spParamCollection[count].TypeName;
                                par.SqlDbType = spParamCollection[count].Type;
                            }
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
                        }
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        return (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
                    }
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        public int executeSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection)
        {

            return executeSP(spName, spParamCollection, false);

        }

        public DataTable getDataUsingSqlQuery(string strSqlQuery)
        {

            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                    connection.Open();
                {
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(strSqlQuery, connection))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        dt = new DataTable();
                        adpt.Fill(dt);
                        return (dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        public int executeSqlQuery(string strSqlQuery)
        {

            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(strSqlQuery, connection))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        intresult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return (intresult);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        public SPParamReturnCollection executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection)
        {
            return executeSPReturnParam(spName, null, spParamReturnCollection);
        }
        public int executeSPReturnParam()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public int executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, ref SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturned = new SPParamReturnCollection();
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        int count, param = 0;
                        if (spParamCollection == null)
                        { param = -1; }
                        else
                        {
                            param = spParamCollection.Count;
                        }
                        for (count = 0; count < param; count++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                        }
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        foreach (SPParams paramReturn in spParamReturnCollection)
                        {
                            SqlParameter _parmReturn = new SqlParameter(paramReturn.Name, paramReturn.Size);
                            _parmReturn.Direction = paramReturn.ParamDirection;
                            if (paramReturn.Size > 0) _parmReturn.Size = paramReturn.Size;
                            else _parmReturn.Size = 32;
                            _parmReturn.SqlDbType = paramReturn.Type;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(_parmReturn);
                        }
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        intresult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();

                        //for (int i = 0; i < spParamReturnCollection.Count; i++)
                        //{
                        //    spParamReturned.Add(new SPParams
                        //    {
                        //        Name = spParamReturnCollection[i].Name,
                        //        Value = cmd.Parameters[spParamReturnCollection[i].Name].Value
                        //    });

                        //}
                    }
                }
                return intresult;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();

            }
        }
        public SPParamReturnCollection executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection)
        {
            return executeSPReturnParam(spName, spParamCollection, spParamReturnCollection, false);
        }
        public SPParamReturnCollection executeSPReturnParam(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection, SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturnCollection, bool addExtraParmas)
        {
            try
            {
                SPParamReturnCollection spParamReturned = new SPParamReturnCollection();
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        int count, param = 0;
                        if (spParamCollection == null)
                        { param = -1; }
                        else
                        {
                            param = spParamCollection.Count;
                        }
                        for (count = 0; count < param; count++)
                        {
                            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                            if (addExtraParmas)
                            {
                                par.TypeName = spParamCollection[count].TypeName;
                                par.SqlDbType = spParamCollection[count].Type;
                            }
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
                         }
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        foreach (SPParams paramReturn in spParamReturnCollection)
                        {
                            SqlParameter _parmReturn = new SqlParameter(paramReturn.Name, paramReturn.Value);
                            _parmReturn.Direction = paramReturn.ParamDirection;
                            if (paramReturn.Size > 0) _parmReturn.Size = paramReturn.Size;
                            else _parmReturn.Size = 32;
                            _parmReturn.SqlDbType = paramReturn.Type;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(_parmReturn);
                        }
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();

                        for (int i = 0; i < spParamReturnCollection.Count; i++)
                        {
                            spParamReturned.Add(new SPParams
                            {
                                Name = spParamReturnCollection[i].Name,
                                Value = cmd.Parameters[spParamReturnCollection[i].Name].Value

                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
                return spParamReturned;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        public object getScalarUsingSP(string spName)
        {
            return getScalarUsingSP(spName, null);
        }
        public object getScalarUsingSP(string spName, SPParamCollection spParamCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(Strcon))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        int count, param = 0;
                        if (spParamCollection == null)
                        { param = -1; }
                        else
                        {
                            param = spParamCollection.Count;
                        }
                        for (count = 0; count < param; count++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(spParamCollection[count].Name, spParamCollection[count].Value);
                            cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        }
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: wow.. you posted out your whole code for us to review.. I think this site is for asking problems.. if you are having some problem with above code please.. specify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see your current approach doesn't care about transactional environment, This days no one care about how to create DAL, when [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), ... are available, I suggest check Entity Framework and use it for startup check [code first](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx). it is available for 2008 and 2010.

Comment: EF or nhibernate which one is better

Comment: @NIGHIL DAS, Depends on your skills, but if you have no experience on them, It's better use Entity framework, It's easy to start, for example Tooks one day for me to use spring and nhibernate for the first time, but using EF takes half an hour (creating simple database and add it and use it) Also EF supports for linq is very better than nhibernate, also EF is faster in .net than nhibernate, (I'm not talking about nhibernate 3.0 because I have no experience on that). but hibernate configs and etc is similar in java and dot net and it's more mature than EF, but I prefer EF.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the opportunity try using an available tool to map from code to a database. [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) is a popular one and also the [MS Entity framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723)

The code you exposed here is quite complex to be asked in this pages, I doubt you will get a specific answer about it.

Answer (score 1):

If i was code reviewing this, i would reject it. My first comment is: that is NOT a data access layer - you could call this a *Data Independence Layer* (in reality you very seldom need one of those).

A data access layer is meant to abstract the data repository from the layer calling it. Exposing functions like `getScalarUsingSP()` and `getDataUsingSP()` is not abstracting the database at all, it is just creating a couple of wrapper functions more suited for your style of calling.

You are on the right track by exposing stuff via an interface, but you need to change the exposed functions. Instead of `getDataUsingSP()` you need to have a call like `GetSelectedAccounts()` or `SaveCustomer()` - the `getDataUsingSP()` would be private and called from within the "friendly" exposed function.